# Unrecognized selector sent to class [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier]

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar, unrecognized-selector

I have an application written in Swift which runs fine on the iOS simulator. The target for the project is set to iOS 7.1.

When I run the app on my iPhone 5s, it crashes at the following line:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSGregorianCalendar)
```

with the error:

```
+[NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1955eee60
```

Do I have to make a different call for iOS8 vs. iOS7.x?

Comment: calendarWithIdentifier is not listed as a method of NSCalendar in the online documentation.

Comment: `calendarWithIdentifier:` *is* available in the iOS 8 SDK.

Comment: @MartinR Actually he's correct `init(identifier:)` is not available anymore. The type signature must have changed between Xcode Beta 1 and Beta 2 releases.  The new signature is `init(calendarIdentifier:)`

Comment: @JuJoDi: I had just looked at the header files. `NSCalendar(identifier: NSGregorianCalendar)` translates to `+[NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:]` which is not available in iOS 7. - `NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)` translates to `[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]` which *is* available in iOS 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though using `NSCalendar(identifier: NSGregorianCalendar)`doesn't throw an error at compile time, what might be a bug, I suppose using `NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)` as stated in the docs.